# Proving that two integral are equal (changing variable of integration)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to prove that
$$
\frac{1}{\beta^2}\int_0^\beta d\tilde{\beta} \frac{n^2 \tilde{\beta}}{e^{\tilde{\beta} n}+1}=-\int_{n}^\infty dz \frac{z}{e^{\beta z}+1}
$$
how do we change the variable of integration?

Comment: Please include some [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) or provide some [source or motivation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29298) to raise this question from being a [PSQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33854).

Answer (score 4):

This is clearly false as you stated it, since (for $\beta>0$) the left-hand side is positive and the right-hand side is negative.

However, substituting $z = \left(\dfrac n\beta\right)\tilde\beta$ gives
$$\frac{n^2}{\beta^2}\int_0^\beta \frac{\tilde\beta\,d\tilde\beta}{e^{\tilde\beta n}+1} = \int_0^n \frac{z\,dz}{e^{\beta z}+1}.$$